# User inputs are not being passed to login function

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript

When I pass an email and password from my app, using nativescript textfields, the login service is not receiving the details

The create user function was working however the login was giving `NullInjectorError: No provider for User!` errors. I added a providers entry into my app.component.ts file and now the user details are not being passed to the login or create user functions

Below is part of my app.component.ts file
    const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

```
import { LoginService, User } from "../shared/";

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: "ns-app",
templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
private _activatedUrl: string;
private _sideDrawerTransition: DrawerTransitionBase;

constructor(private router: Router,
            private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,
            private userService: LoginService) {
```

Below is my login.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { User } from "./user.model";

const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    user = new User;
    constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions/*,
                private user: User*/) {
    }

    register(/*user*/) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("Creating user: " + this.user.email);
            firebase.createUser(
                {
                    email: this.user.email,
                    password: this.user.password
                })
                .then(
                    function (user) {
                                     alert("User created, email: " + this.user.email)
                                    },
                    function (errorMessage) {
                                             alert("Error: " + errorMessage)
                    }
                );
        })
    }

    login(/*user*/) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("Login.service.ts: Logging in user: " + this.user.email);
            firebase.login(
                {
                    type: firebase.LoginType.PASSWORD,
                    passwordOptions: {
                        email: this.user.email,
                        password: this.user.password
                    }
                })
                .then(result => JSON.stringify(result))
                .catch(error => console.log("Login.service. Error: " + error));
        });
    }

    logout() {
        firebase.logout();
        this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/login"]);
    };
}
```

Below is my login.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { setString } from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";
import { alert, LoginService, User } from "../shared";

@Component({
    selector: "Login",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html"
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User;

    isLoggingIn = true;
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,
        private page: Page,
        private userService: LoginService
    ) {
        /*this.user = new User();*/
    }

    toggleDisplay() {
        this.isLoggingIn = !this.isLoggingIn;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }

    submit() {
        console.log("Submit button pressed");
        if (!this.user.isValidEmail()) {
            alert("Enter a valid email address.")

            return;
        }

        if (this.isLoggingIn) {
            console.log("triggering login");
            this.login(/*this.user*/);
        } else {
            this.signUp(/*this.user*/);
        }
    }

    login(/*user*/) {
        console.log("Login triggered");
        console.log("User email: " + this.user.email);
        console.log("User password: " + this.user.password);
        this.userService.login(/*this.user*/)
            .then(status => {
                setString("userID", String(this.user.email));
                this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/home"], { clearHistory: true });
            }, err => {
                this.clearFields();
                alert("Unfortunately we could not find your account.")
            });
    }

    signUp(/*user*/) {
        this.userService.register(/*this.user*/)
            .then(status => {
                alert("Your account was successfully created.");
                this.toggleDisplay();
                this.clearFields();
            }, err => {
                this.clearFields();
                alert("Unfortunately we were unable to create your account.")
            });
    }

    clearFields() {
        this.user.email = "";
        this.user.password = "";
    }

}
```

Below is my login.component.html file

```
<FlexboxLayout class="login Roboto">
    <StackLayout class="form" [class.dark]="!isLoggingIn">
        <Image class="image" src="~/images/logo.png"></Image>

        <TextField hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" [(ngModel)]="user.email" class="input input-border"></TextField>
        <TextField hint="Password" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="user.password" class="input input-border"></TextField>

        <Button [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign in' : 'Sign up'" class="btn btn-primary" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
        <Button class="btn btn-secondary" [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign up' : 'Back to login'" (tap)="toggleDisplay()"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

I am expecting the email and password details to be passed from the textfields in the html into the login service login and create user functions.

Comment: You are passing `user` as a parameter to `login` function in the service but trying to access the class member in the function definition. You are not suppose to inject user as dependency unless you mark that as a [provider](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers), if you decide to mark that as a provider then you should inject user class in login component too, so both service and component will share the object and values will be updated.

Comment: I'm sorry @Manoj, could you please clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The signatures of the html-file `submit` function is not the same as in the ts file. 
(`submit()` vs `submit(user)` [therefore user is undefined in your function]) Try fixing that. (Maybe stick with `submit()` and use the class variable user)

And I would suggest to remove the `providers` from the component declaration and instead import the shared module (with its providers) on root / login module level.

Comment: I've tried that.
The text in my buttons on the login screen has disappeared and I'm getting the following error when I start the app/trying to log in.
```JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined```